# Nginx URI path port redirect unexpected behaviour with Docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I deployed a Docker container on port 8080.
I configured my nginx server to point to port 8080 in nginx.config like so:

```
server {
   ...
   location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   }
   ...
```

This worked fine and the calls to server were redirected to docker container.

I now needed to point different URI paths to different containers. 
For example I needed /service1 path to point to my original docker container. So i did this:

```
server {
   ...
   location / {
   }

   location /service1 {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   }
```

I am following this guide here: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0#step-5----add-blog-and-mail

I did nginx -s reload and restart but I get a Whitelabel error when I navigate to {IP_ADDRESS}/service1. Canńot understand this.

Does it has something to do with the location / {} being emtpy?

**EDIT**

As suggested I redepolyed my container on 8090 and changed the nginx.config file to this:

```
server {
   ...
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   }

   location /service1 {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
   }
```

Put when I HTTP to [IP_ADDRESS]/service1 I still get 404.

**EDIT2**

As suggested I changed the nginx.conf file to avoid passing the "service1" to container but the error response suggests that it still receives it.

nginx.conf:

```
location / {
}

location = /service1 {
    return 302 /service1/;
}

location /service1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
}
```

Error:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2018-04-07T09:56:44.600+0000",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "message": "No message available",
   "path": "/service1/image"
}
```

Just to be clear, this error is generated by Docker not Ngnix so the redirect is working?

Comment: possibly, try putting a root dir definition there to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that the `/service1` path is being passed to your container which then responds with a 404 because it doesn't know what to do with it.

Try the following which should strip `/service1` from the path:

```
location = /service1 {
    return 302 /service1/;
}

location /service1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/;
}
```

Note that the trailing slashes are significant and must be respected.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't change the behavior. Added the error response in Edits (still the same).

Comment: While the syntax you provided didn't work, this one did: "location /service1{rewrite ^/service1(.*) /$1 break;proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090}"